# Im getting errors with some methods

Tags: java, arrays, bluej, tui

I'm writing this java class which is the TUI for the Class loyaltyCard, However, I'm facing some errors with the methods below. Would appreciate any help, Thanks.

1. public void addLoyalty Card
2. public void ShowAllLoyaltyCards (**it should print details of all loyaltycards with a space between each)**
3. public void showLoyaltyCard (print out loyaltycard with the choose card number, if unsuccessful  "message"

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoyaltyCardTUI
{

    private LoyaltyCardList loyaltyCardList;
    private Scanner myScanner;

    public LoyaltyCardTUI()
    {
        myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        LoyaltyCardList loyaltyCardList = new LoyaltyCardList();
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        int command = -1;
        while (command != 0)
        {   
            displayMenu();
            command = getCommand();
            execute (command);
        }
    }

    **public void addLoyaltyCard(**)
    {
        loyaltyCardList.addLoyaltyCard(new LoyaltyCard());
    }

    private void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println( "Options are" );
        System.out.println( "Enter 1" );
        System.out.println( "Enter 2" );
        System.out.println( "Enter 3" );
        System.out.println( "Enter 4" );

    }

    private void execute( int command)
    {
        if ( command == 1)
            addLoyaltyCard();
        else
        if ( command == 2 )
            getNumberOfLoyaltyCards();
        else
        if ( command == 3)
            quitCommand();
        else
        if ( command == 4)
            quitCommand();
        else
        if ( command == 5)
            quitCommand();
        else
            System.out.println("Unknown Command");
    }

    private int getCommand()
    {
        System.out.print ("Enter command: ");
        int command = myScanner.nextInt();
        myScanner.nextLine(); 
        return command;
    }

    public void getNumberOfLoyaltyCards()
    {
        int command = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("We have" + loyaltyCardList.getNumberOfLoyaltyCards() + "loyaltyCards");
    }

    public void quitCommand()
    {
        int command = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Application Closing");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void removeLoyaltyCard()
    {     
        System.out.print("Enter card number : ");
        String cardNumber = myScanner.nextLine();
        if (loyaltyCardList.removeLoyaltyCard(cardNumber))
            System.out.println("LoyaltyCard with card number  " + cardNumber + " removed from class list");
        else
            System.out.println("LoyaltyCard with card number " + cardNumber + " not  found");
    }

    **public void showAllLoyaltyCards()**
    {
        for(LoyaltyCard loyaltyCard : loyaltyCards)
        {
            loyaltyCard.printCustomerDetails();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    **public void showLoyaltyCard()**
    {
        for (LoyaltyCard loyaltyCard : loyaltyCards)
        {
            if (cardNumber.equals(loyaltyCard.getCardNumber()))
            {
                return System.out.println(loyaltyCard);
            }
            else
            {
                return System.out.println("Could not find loyalty card for card number"+cardNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    private void unknownCommand(int command)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Command : "+ command);
    }
}
```

Comment: *However, im facing some errors with the methods below.* **What** errors?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it is not compiling

Comment: And what error does the compiler give you? And on what lines? And what was it about the error that you didn't understand?

Comment: Can we see the implementation for the LoyaltyCard and LoyaltyCardList classes?

Comment: however, a problem i can immediately see is that `Sys.out.println()` does not return anything. So you cannot use return with that statement. Also keep in mind that the function that is in is `void`, so you could probably just omit the `return` word altogether